# Multisig Setup - Pruned Bitcoin Core on Computer vs. Dedicated Hardware

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, security, multi-signature, full-node

#### Are there security implications of running a pruned Bitcoin Core node on a personal computer vs. a full Bitcoin Core node on a dedicated hardware device (i.e. Raspberry Pie with Umbrel, myNode, nodl, and etc.)?

- The intended use case for the Bitcoin Core node is integration with a multisig wallet such as Specter, Electrum, and etc.
- This scenario presumes the personal computer is configured to run Bitcoin Core through Tor/VPN (That do not save/collect logs) as in the *[Specter desktop 1-click setup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VWze8xtH72I&t=78s)*.
  [image]
- One non-security implication is the performance impact on the personal computer when running the pruned Bitcoin Core node.

Answer (score 1):

**Both a full Bitcoin and pruned node can be run from Bitcoin Core with the same level of security.**

Pruned nodes have the following differences:

- Does not keep the full blockchain on disk
- Size limit is defined by the user
- Will discard unnecessary block data as it synchronizes

As a user on the Bitcoin Talk forum explains, most "dedicated hardware" Bitcoin Nodes are software wrappers around Bitcoin Core which may be less secure than running Bitcoin Core directly.

*See [Multisig Setup - Pruned Bitcoin Core on Computer vs. Dedicated Hardware](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5335147) - bitcointalk.org*